# Running a query inside the same connection in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

There is a need to run the second sql query (**query2**) after building it using results of first query (**query1**) in mentioned space in code snippet, this second sql query will be generated according to the results of first query. but when I tried to run this, it builds the second query without any issue, but it is not executing. Can someone help to correct this.

```
let userNames ="'";
let query1="SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid in ('1','2','3','4')"

conn.connect().then(function(){
    let req1=new sql.Request(conn);
    req1.query(query1).then(function(recordset){            
        recordset.recordset.map((item)=>{
            userNames=userNames.concat(item.user_name+"','");
        })
        userNames=userNames.slice(0, -2);
                 
        query2=`SELECT * FROM INVOICEMASTER WHERE username IN (${userNames})`
        
        console.log('----------------------------------')   

            **//// Need to execute query2 here**
            
        console.log('before closing the con')
        conn.close();
        console.log('after closing the con')       
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
        conn.close();
    });
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: @DipanshuMahla, query2 is correctly building per program, I can see it when I log it in the console. but when I try to execute it, the connection is closing before executing it. therefore the query2 will not run. do you have any idea?

Comment: @IsharaKularatna as mysql query is async in nature so `conn.close()` will run before your 2nd query. You should use async/await or promise then close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is Asynchronous so each function call will execute separately and all the other execute without waiting for the previous functions.

So when you execute:

```
req1.query(query2).then((data)=>{
     ** process your data **
});

conn.close();
```

The query will be executed in a separate thread but the event loop will continue and close the connection.

The solution to that would:

1. Async Await

   ```
   req1.query(query1).then(async function(recordset){            
        recordset.recordset.map((item)=>{
            userNames=userNames.concat(item.user_name+"','");
        });
        userNames=userNames.slice(0, -2);

        query2=`SELECT * FROM INVOICEMASTER WHERE username IN (${userNames})`;

        var query2Data = await req1.query(query2);

        ** process query2Data here **

        conn.close();

   });
   ```
2. Close the SQL connection in the second query execution callback function.

   ```
   req1.query(query1).then(async function(recordset){            
        recordset.recordset.map((item)=>{
            userNames=userNames.concat(item.user_name+"','");
        });
        userNames=userNames.slice(0, -2);

        query2=`SELECT * FROM INVOICEMASTER WHERE username IN (${userNames})`;

        req1.query(query2).then( function(data){

            ** process query2Data here **
            conn.close();
        });

   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I could use below way to achieve this by wrapping the function call into a promise and then used await to get the result even though I was looking for run the second query inside the first one, using this way I could build the second query to run it.

This is posting fur reference :

I could use await for the result using await function

```
let userNames ="'";
let query1="SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid in ('1','2','3','4')"

function usernamesGenerator(query, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        
        conn.connect().then(function(){
            let req1=new sql.Request(conn);
            req1.query(query).then(function(recordset){            
                recordset.recordset.map((item)=>{
                    userNames =userNames.concat(item.user_name+"','");
                })
                userNames=userNames .slice(0, -2);
                successCallback(userNames);  
                conn.close();                  
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err)
                errorCallback(err);
                conn.close();
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            errorCallback(err);
        });   
        
    }
    function usernamesGeneratorfunctionWrapper(query) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            usernamesGenerator(query,(successResponse) => {
                resolve(successResponse);
            }, (errorResponse) => {
                reject(errorResponse)
            });
        });
    }
    async function runLogic() {
        try {
            const user_names = await usernamesGenerator(query1);
            console.log("Invoices2 in business logic: "+user_names);
            
            /* Bulding query 2 & executing it can be done here */
            let query2=`SELECT * FROM INVOICEMASTER WHERE username IN (${user_names})`
        
        } catch(error) {
            console.error("ERROR:" + error);
        }
    }
    
    runLogic();
```